# Remove duplicate lines on two columns on a .csv

Tags: bash, csv, awk, grep

I'd like to find duplicates on a csv file over bash with a pipe as field separator.

Let's take an example :

Input:

```
W14|E75  
Z20|K60  
R59|R59  
K60|O74  
A08|M10
```

Expected output :

```
Z20|K60  
R59|R59  
K60|O74
```

Else other expected output :

```
Z20|K60  
R59|R59
```

I mean when the expression already exist in the first column, just keep it, the same with the second column, else I can accept to keep only the first line.

What I tried is :

```
awk -F "|" 'FNR==NR { x[$1,$2]++; next } x[$1,$2] > 1' file.csv file.csv
```

I think about using a grep but i'm not quiet sure how to do it.

Sorry for bad english and thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "expression" and "just keep it"? Please, to make your question clearer, first describe ONLY what your ideal solution would look like, and then SEPARATELY describe what compromise you would be willing to make. As it is now, it's too confusing.

Comment: Yes - what's duplicate about W14 or E75?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you mean by "duplicate" in your examples. Please clarify!

Answer (score 2):

I think based on the output, you want the non unique entries regardless of their position in the lines

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;a[$2]++;next} a[$1]*a[$2]>1' file{,}
```

should give you your first output.

Comment: That's some deep understanding, sir. :thethumbupemojioracouple: